# How long would it take for the US consulate to issue a B1/B2 visa to an Iranian citizen after a successful interview?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, turkey, iran, ankara

Pardon me if this is a duplicate question, but I simply could not find an answer here, on the State Department's site, or on usvisa-info.com.

**How long does a US embassy take to "stamp" and return an applicant's passport after a successful B2 visa interview?**

The State Department's [site](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html#) lists an average "appointment wait time" of 4 days, but I'm not sure if this is:

1. How long an applicant should expect to wait for an open appointment slot.

OR

2. How long an applicant should expect to wait after his/her interview to receive docs.

[image: wait time table]

Clicking "see details" does nothing to show information about "Visa Processing Wait Times" which are explained at the bottom of the page.

**Note**, I'm inquiring for relatives in Iran. I know their chances are practically non-existent, but they *insist* on applying. I ask about the processing time because they'll need to book a trip to Turkey for the interview, and they'll need their passports back before they can return to Iran.

Comment: Interesting. From everything I have read, that tool is _also_ supposed to display the processing time, but it does not. In any case, the interviewing officer can advise of the processing time at the time of the interview.

Comment: VTC: IMHO with the ongoing political climate, any response would be speculative, not very prudent. OP has not returned since posting.